# C# I'm stuck in a loop due to "error 307 temporary redirected"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a website but I'm facing a 307 temporary redirected error.

here is my code :

```
do
{
   try
   {
       using (XmlReader nfo_catcher = XmlReader.Create(p))
       {
           SyndicationFeed feed_nfo = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
           p = "";
       }
   }
   catch (System.Net.WebException e)
   {
       p = e.Response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri;
   }
} while(p != "");
```

The code inside the DO part works fine in my RSS reader, but here where I try to get to the website, it return me the temporary redirected error witch I tryed to solve with the catch section , unsuccessfully.

Any idea how I can catch the good URI ?

thx,
Artanis

Comment: The redirect URI should be located in the response headers, under the `Location` header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm releaved that someone understand my request I've been searching yesterday all day and only finding topics about stting up redirections on web servers... 

Under the location header I have : "X-frame-options"
I have a total of 15 headers you wanna see the list ?

Comment: I meant that the `Location` header contains the URI as value (not literally underneath it in the options). E.g. `p = e.Response.Headers.Location`

Comment: ^^ Ok thx I get the good URI now, but it seems that I cannot access the website anyway. 
Because at some point he starts giving weird adresses, apparently he wants me to accept cookies, I'll look into it =) Thx to you!

Comment: ok good. I'll post it as anwser then.

Comment: yeah I could find the right Uri thanks to you, but I was unsucessfull about reaching the website anyway... ='(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a redirect (http status code 301, 302, 303, 307 & 308) you'll receive a response where the URI is located in the `Location` header.

In C# you can find the header in your response using:

```cs
context.Response.Headers.Location
```